# Open an URL in a web browser and refresh it continuously from C# app

Tags: url, browser, refresh

How can I develop a C# application to open a page in a web browser, given the URL, and refresh it continuously (always the same URL).

Answer (score 3):

Make a javascript function that polls the url (e.g. via [`window.setTimeout()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536753(VS.85).aspx)).
(Either using [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for partially updating the content, or setting [`window.location.href`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.location), etc..)